# What is the best practice, have JavaScript in a Visualforce page, or a third-party server

Tags: visualforce, cti, opencti

I working on OpenCTI integration. Right now I am serving all the open cti script and HTML page from a http server. 
What is the best practice to connect to open cti scripts(interaction.js)? having it in visual force page or serving from a web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend having it stored locally either inside the VF page or hosted inside your Salesforce org as a static resource. Having the script residing on another server has downsides like:

- It can be changed by a 3rd party without a notice which potentially may lead to multitude of security risks
- The server might be down and your page won't work, or the server might have performance issues and it'll take longer to load, you're introducing dependencies

The only downside of having it locally is that you'll need to manually update it when an updated version of the script comes out.